# Interferences with iPhone Simulator and real iPhone

Tags: iphone, simulator

I developed my App and everything seems to be finished. The App is running perfectly under the IOS Simulator. (The App displays a TableView)

Now I want to test it on my iPhone, but the APP Crashed with the exception, that he could not find the ReuseIdentifier of a TableViewCell.

I do the same thing on iPhone Simulator again and all works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Check the case of your reuse identifier and where you use that identifier in your code. The Simulator is NOT case sensitive. The actual devices ARE. e.g. `thisIdentifier` is not the same as `thisidentifier`

Comment: Set some breakpoints and step through to see what is happening when it crashes and what reuse identifier it is using.

Comment: I did some outputs and saw, that the ReuseIdentifier equals the ReuseIdentifier of the storyboard. But I changed the TableViewController and replaced it with a brand new TableViewController (also named a Cell "Cell"), First Responder is my TableViewController Class. And also the brand new TableViewController displays the same error message (He can not find the ReuseIdentifier. Is there a way to display all ReuseIdentifiers of a tableView Object?

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and actually examine the code as it was running to see what is going on? If you don't know what I mean, please go and read some tutorials on debugging using breakpoints and the interactive debugger rather than trying to write things to the console/labels, etc.

Comment: I set the breakpoint and all seems to be ok, the tableView and the indexPath are set and much more is not happening. These are the lines of code: NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; return cell;

Comment: Have you checked the prototype cell in your storyboard has the same name?

Comment: Yes, it is the same name: "Cell", I think it might be the tableView object is wrong. Is there a possibility to show all cells of the tableview object with its reuseidentifiers?